# What to do if SetEnvIf regex could not be compiled

Tags: kerberos, apache-virtualhost

In our company we are working with apache vhosts and kerberos.

I changed the kerberos.inc file. I added one line:

```
 SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For ^1\.[1-3]\.[0-255]\.[1-254] env_var
```

Now when I'm restarting the apache with `rcapache2 graceful` I'm getting the error: SetEnvIf regex could not be compiled.

What does this error mean? Why am I receiving this error even if there are already lines like the one i added, but with other numbers.

Comment: `[0-255]` matches `0`, `1`, `2`, and `5`; this line wouldn't do what you think it's doing in the best case. I don't know if that's relevant to the error message or not.

Comment: Do you know what I'm trying to do? If so, can you tell me how you would write this line?

Comment: @MichaelHomer Ok, I changed the Regex as you told me to. It works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Regex.

`[0-255]` is not what you want. `([0-9]|[1-8][0-9]|9[0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])` is the right Regex. Change all your little parts to the right Regex and it should work.